# Open popup dialog window on button click in Python AddIn?

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I'm trying to figure out a way to display an image in a dialog box that will be used for a help menu for my toolbar addins.

The best scenario i've found is using the pythonaddins module and the messagebox popup, but can't figure out how to any formatting, except pure text string.

Is there another way to display information that i can call via a button click.

Comment: Python Add-Ins are pretty limited on this type of functionality.  Since you are wanting to create help content, perhaps it would be easier to create an HTML page and open that when the user clicks on a button?  You wouldn't even need to host it from a web server, you could just package it up in the install folder.

Comment: Ah cheers, will go that route, I thought about using html earlier but couldn't find any information on opening up a html from a button onclick? 
Cheers for the quick response

Comment: That part is easy.  For your `onClick()` method, you can use the builtin [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) module to call the HTML file: `webbrowser.open(r'path\to\your\help_page.html')`.  If you package this up in the `install` folder where the script resides, it is very easy to make it find it from the relative path.

Comment: @crmackey Your comments look worth writing up as a short answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo, thanks.  I have summarized my comments into a short answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comments, I think making a simple HTML page to serve as help documentation would be the easiest solution.  Python Add Ins are fairly limited with pop up options.  The HTML page wouldn't need to be hosted on a web server and can just be included in the `install` directory of the Add In and use relative paths to open this when the `onClick()` method is invoked.

The HTML doc can easily be opened using the builtin [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) module.  So if you have a structure like this:

```
Your_AddIn_Name
    \install
        Your_AddIn_Name.py
        help.html
```

You can open your `help.html` file in a web browser by adding this to your `onClick()` method:

```
# Your_AddIn_Name.py
import webbrowser
# code...
class SomeToolClass(object):
    # code...
    def onClick(self):
        webbrowser.open('help.html')
```